# Installing ubuntustudio-audio, getting errors

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio

I get this error when I try and install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-audio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ubuntustudio-audio : Depends: libavdevice-extra-53 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libavfilter-extra-3 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libavformat-extra-54 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libavutil-extra-52 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libswscale-extra-2 but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: ardour3 but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: audacity but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: idjc but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: pd-aubio but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: pd-readanysf but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

At the top of this page - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio/PackageList it
says =OUTDATED=. I'm not sure if that's referring to the whole page (and why
this install isn't working) or if it's just referring to the first thing on there (`ubuntustudio-desktop`).

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Raphael added system info to OP, cheers

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks - using aptitude instead seems to have helped with that, I guess it was something on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe" && sudo apt-get update
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-audio
```

If the above doesn't work, other way is to download the packages manually and then install it from there. To do so:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/ubuntustudio && cd ~/Downloads/ubuntustudio
```

Downloads the following packages manually (while still in the folder `~/Downloads/ubuntustudio`):

[security.ubuntu.com libavdevice-extra-53](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavdevice-extra-53_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb)

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavdevice-extra-53_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

[security.ubuntu.com libavfilter-extra-3](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavfilter-extra-3_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb)

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavfilter-extra-3_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

[security.ubuntu.com libavformat-extra-54](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavformat-extra-54_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb)

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavformat-extra-54_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

[security.ubuntu.com libavutil-extra-52](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavutil-extra-52_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb)

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavutil-extra-52_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

[security.ubuntu.com libswscale-extra-2](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libswscale-extra-2_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb)

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libswscale-extra-2_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
```

Then, to install it run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

And to satisfy any dependencies, do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```